# Is "go" infinitive or indicative?

Tags: verb-forms

In the question "Did you go swimming?", is the verb "go" in infinitive form or in present indicative? How can we tell which form it is?

Comment: `do` combines with the unmarked form of the infinitive.   `do` is inflected for number and tense; the other verb that it combines with is not inflected.  *She does **has** a nice singing voice* and *Does she **has** a nice singing voice?* are ungrammatical.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is the **Infinitive**. The most simple test is putting a similar question in the 3rd person (singular):

> Does/did **he go** swimming?

As you can see, the verb 'go' doesn't take '-**es**' here while 'do' can be modified so. An example of a question with present indicative of 'to go':

> Is it true that he **goes** swimming now?

Comment: Sorry, my question was about "Did you go swimming?", not "Do you go swimming?". I've already made the edits.

Comment: OK, my fault - changed 'does' to 'did' now.

Comment: How does the fact that the verb doesn't take "-es" prove that "go" in "Did he go swimming?" is infinitive and not indicative form?

Comment: You can answer as well with an emphasis: Yes, he did **go** swimming.

Comment: So, how do we know that "go" in "Yes, he did go swimming" is the infinitive and not the indicative form? I don't understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82228/discussion-between-brilliant-and-alex-ander).